# Why are the bleachers called the bleachers?

Tags: etymology

While I was reading about why the 'nosebleed' seats are called such a preposterous name at the ballpark, my curiosity was piqued in reference to another ballpark term that has troubled me over the years. The bench-like cheap seats have always been referred to as "bleachers". I have wondered why my whole life and have asked no less than 3 wise men / gurus, but to no avail. Won't you all please resolve this issue for me and my linguistically starved children?

Answer (score 3):

The [bleachers](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bleacher) were so named because the boards were bleached by the sun.

> The "bench for spectators at a sports field" sense (usually bleachers) is attested since 1889, American English; so named because the boards were bleached by the sun.

Comment: We don't seem to use the term over here in the UK ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth They have sun in the UK?

Comment: Look. My wife and I did your 'Grand Circle' tour in 2012, and it rained! It's not just a British thing. (OK, I admit it only rained for 30 seconds out of 14 days.)

Comment: choster, the sun turns up even in the UK. It's just the word *bleachers* that does not.

Answer (score 0):

NRS does a good job explaining why are bleachers called bleachers: https://www.bleachers.net/why-are-bleachers-called-bleachers

Comment: Sorry, a link is useless: please [**quote the relevant portion.**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370) And in this case, the relevant portion says nothing more than the existing answer.

Comment: Your reference is pretty good.  Please edit your reply to copy a few of the most relevant lines from it.